# How to use fonts on TextView from URL (website) - in android?

Tags: android, textview, android-typeface

Hi i am trying to build app where some fonts are loaded from **URL** and then apply on **`TextView`** but it's don't work.

**Here my simple code**

in oncreate()

```
try {
     if (new File("/sdcard/a/" + MainActivity.pos + ".ttf").exists()){
        mTypeface = Typeface.createFromFile("/sdcard/a/" + MainActivity.pos
         + ".ttf");
         tv.setTypeface(mTypeface);
     } else {
         new DisplayImageFromURL().execute(MainActivity.URL);
     }
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Downloading and show font style on TextView

```
private class DisplayImageFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Typeface> {
                ProgressDialog pd=null;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd = new ProgressDialog(Working_Class.this);
            pd.setMessage("Downoading file...");
            pd.show();
        }

        protected Typeface doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Typeface mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                mIcon11=Typeface.createFromFile(urldisplay);//this line not working properly....

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Typeface result) {
            mTextView.setTypeface(result);
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

**and i want to like this**

[image] 
[image]

Comment: You need to download the font and save at your local storage. After that, you will load it using local path in ```Typeface.createFromFile(LOCAL_PATH)```, not the remote path.

Comment: question is updated but how to do like this first download then use???

Comment: Do some research on downloading assets and/or ask a new question

Comment: I too facing this problem its confusing me